# A C program with memory leak in valgrind on Linux but I have freed mem from malloc()

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am doing C++ program for a real application project.

I use valgrind to do memory leak check.

I got :

160 bytes in 10 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==14312==    at 0x4A0846F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)

But, I have called free() to release it.

How to fix it ? Why I have memory leak ?

Any help will be appreciated. !

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int * GetSomeIDs() ; 
/*-------- GetSomeIDs-----*/

typedef struct {
       char* alias;   /* '\0'-terminated C string */
       int   specific_id;
} aliasID;

int GetNumberOfAliases(void)
{
    return 10;
}

aliasID *GetNextAlias(void)
{
    aliasID *p = (aliasID *) malloc(sizeof(aliasID)) ;
    p->alias = "test alias";
    p->specific_id = rand();
    return p; 
}

int *GetSomeIDs2(aliasID  ***a, int *aIDsize , int *idSize)
{
    int  *ids  = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 8) ;  
    *idSize = 8 ; 
    int length = GetNumberOfAliases();
    *aIDsize = length ;
    int i  ;
    *a = (aliasID**) malloc(sizeof(aliasID*)*length) ;

    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i)
    {
        (*a)[i] = GetNextAlias();
    }

    return  ids; 
}

void callGetSomeIDs()
{
    aliasID  **aD = NULL;
    int mySize = -1; 
    int myidSize = -1; 
    int *pt = NULL;
    pt = GetSomeIDs2(&aD, &mySize, &myidSize); 
    if (!pt || !aD || mySize <= 0 || myidSize <= 0)
    {
        printf("there is a runt time error of GetSomeIDs \n");
        if (!pt && aD)
        {
            printf("there is a runt time error of GetSomeIDs pt is NULL \n");
            free(aD);
        }
    if (!aD && pt)
        {
            printf("there is a runt time error of GetSomeIDs aD is NULL \n");
            free(pt);
        }
        if (!pt && !aD)
        {
            printf("there is a runt time error of GetSomeIDs aD and pt all NULL \n");
        }

        exit(1);
    }
    // print out 8 int
    printf("the followings are integers  \n");
    int i ;
    for(i = 0 ; i < myidSize ; ++i )
    {
        printf("%d " , pt[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // print out alias and ID 
    printf("the followings are alias and ID  \n");
    for (i = 0 ; i <  mySize   ; ++i )
    {
        printf( "alias is  %s " , (*aD[i]).alias) ;   
            printf( "specific_id is  %d", (*aD[i]).specific_id) ;
        printf("\n") ;
    }

    free(pt);
    free(aD);
  }

  int main()
  {

      callGetSomeIDs();

      return 0; 
   }
```

Comment: I don't see any C++ here. Maybe you want to relace the C++ tag with C?

Comment: Sorry, i have changed it for c tag. thanks !

Comment: First of all, you might want to rethink your design, as it's pretty unusual to use triple indirection.  Also, when calling malloc try to always use sizeof( varName ) instead of sizeof( type ).

Comment: `int  *ids  =  malloc(sizeof(int) * 8) ; ` is better. Cast is NOT needed and will make some mistake Invisible.

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes, why should one use var and not var type? Any advantages of using var opposed to var type?

Comment: @tuxuday, if you change the variable type then it will automatically update. e.g. `int* ids = malloc(8 * sizeof(*ids));`

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes I wouldn't say that as +. As the opposite fails, that if i change var name then it wouldn't automatically update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You free the array of `aliasID` structures, but not the allocated entries in the array.

**Edit:**

You allocate first an array of `aliasID` pointers, then for each entry in the array you allocate the actual `aliasID`. You need to free the `aliasID` pointers in the array first before you free the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length_of_array; i++)
    free(aD[i]);
free(ad);
```

Comment: I have freed the memory according to http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/free/

Comment: Your reference uses realloc. You have to free the memory you allocated in `GetNextAlias` function

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but if your code enters the if after GetSomeIDs2, you do an exit(1), so your free could wouldn't run.

You also don't free the memory returned from GetNextAlias();